# Ruby string split with space as input removes more than just spaces

Tags: ruby, string, split

I have some text that has this particular character: 
When I call the string split() method (with just ' ' as the input)  , the  gets removed. What should I do to keep the ?

Comment: Seems like that character is U+000C, i.e. _form feed_. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow doesn't allow to post control characters literally. You can use `"\u000c"` or `"\f"` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected behavior when passing `' '`. According to the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#split-method):

> If *pattern* is a single space, *str* is split on whitespace, with leading and trailing whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace characters ignored.

With "whitespace" being space (`" "`) and `\t`, `\n`, `\v`, `\f`, `\r`.

```
"foo bar\nbaz \f qux".split(' ')
#=> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]
```

To split on space (U+0020) only, you have to use a regexp:

```
"foo bar\nbaz \f qux".split(/ /)
#=> ["foo", "bar\nbaz", "\f", "qux"]
```